# Angularjs Skype URI "onclick" issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, skype, skype-uri.js

Im trying to implement [Skype Button](http://www.skype.com/en/features/skype-buttons/create-skype-buttons/) on the website Im working on using `Angularjs`

The code provided by the Skype API is the following

```
</script>
<div id="SkypeButton_Call_mike_1">
  <script type="text/javascript">
    Skype.ui({
      "name": "dropdown",
      "element": "SkypeButton_Call_mike_1",
      "participants": ["mike"],
      "imageSize": 32
    });
  </script>
</div>
```

Im using `angularjs` so the `mike` pseudo comes from my angular `model` (Controller).

```
$scope.user.skypePseudo = "mike"
```

**Then when I change**

```
"participants": ["mike"]
```

**to**

```
"participants": ["{{user.skypePseudo}}"]
```

**It throws this error**

```
Interpolations for HTML DOM event attributes are disallowed.  Please use the ng- versions (such as ng-click instead of onclick) instead.
```

The error is clear, it means I cannot use **onclick** and should use **ng-click** instead.

I have tried to modifiy the [skype-uri.js](http://www.skypeassets.com/i/scom/js/skype-uri.js) by replacing all `onclick` by `ng.click` but get some compliation errors.

Is there someone that have experienced this before me ? How can I make it working ?

**The question could be asked as** : is there a way to **force** angular to accept **onclick**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the best way to achieve that is to create a new directive:

```
angular.module("yourApp")
.directive("skypeUi", function() {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        template: "<div></div>",
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            participants: "="
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){
            Skype.ui({
                "name": "dropdown",
                "element": attrs.id,
                "participants": scope.participants,
                "imageSize": 32
            });
        }
    };
});
```

So you can use like that;

```
<skype-ui id="SkypeButton_Call_mike_1" participants="participants">
</skype-ui>
```

And finally in your controller:

```
$scope.participants = ["mike"];
```

Comment: Copy pasted your code and it is working like a charm ! Thanks a lot !